# Gnocanvas.canvas's coordinate on the window in Lablgtk2

Tags: window, gtk, ocaml

I'm using Lablgtk2.
I want to show 500x400 window by using GnoCanvas module, so I write as below.

```
let window = GWindow.window ~show:true ~width:500 ~height:400 () in
let canvas = GnoCanvas.canvas ~width:500 ~height:400 () in
ignore(GnoCanvas.rect 
         ~props:[`FILL_COLOR "#ffffff";`X1 0.;`Y1 0.;`X2 500.;`Y2 400.]
                                                           canvas#root); 

window#add (canvas#coerce);
window#show ();
GMain.Main.main ()
```

I think 500x400 white window is shown, but it is shown that 500x400 window which has 300x250 white rectangle at the lower right.
I think the canvas's coordinates (0,0) are coordinates (200,150) at the window.
I can't understand why it should be so and what is wrong at the code.
Please tell me the collect code.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome canvas uses [three coordinate systems](https://developer.gnome.org/libgnomecanvas/stable/GnomeCanvas.html). Just to be sure that world coordinate system corresponds one-to-one to pixels, consider using this two canvas methods: `set_pixels_per_unit` and `set_scroll_region`. I've not tested it, but doing the following can help:

```
canvas#set_pixels_per_unit 1.0;
canvas#set_scroll_region 0 0 500 400;
```